# Overlay a 3D density on a map in R

Tags: r

I have a map of Chicago city with identified thefts(red dots) according on latitude and longitude. I want to overlay the 3D density of the thefts on the map of Chicago with the red dots. The 3D density can be find in the following way:

```
library(MASS)
C1=kde2d(Lat, Long, n = 40, lims = c(41.7,42,-87.5,-87.8))
persp(x =sort(C1$x),y =sort(C1$y),z=C1$z, xlim =c(41.7,42), ylim =c(-87.8,-87.5), 
zlim =c(0,150),xlab="Latitude",ylab="Longitude",zlab="Density",phi=45)
```

Now, I want the 3D density with a R image of the map under it. I tried to read the documentation on "rgl" package, but I did not find anything that could help me.

Any hint would be really appreciate.

Comment: I tried to download the data, but it took ages and I cancelled the code. Would it be possible for you to provide a minimum data from the data set?

Comment: I did a sample with only 30 datalines. Here is the link: [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxksLxUS73CZcTVkbFVTVVhNRHc/view?usp=sharing). Also, here is the link to the real data set(the big one): [real dataset](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2)

Comment: I wonder if you wanna use the `plotKML` package. See [this](http://gsif.isric.org/doku.php?id=wiki:tutorial_plotkml).

Comment: I don't know this package, but if it allows me to overlay a 3D density on a map, then I am willing to use it.